# numpy: referencing elements in reverse order

Tags: python, numpy

I am a bit confused on how to reference elements of a numpy array in reverse order: For example:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]])
print(arr[1:3,:]) #gives me
[[ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
```

However

```
print(arr[3:1,:]  #gives me
[]
```

Is there anyway I can start at element 3 and print backwards till element 1?
So expected output is

```
[[11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You can do: `arr[2:0:-1]`

Comment: Lists and numpy arrays can be sliced backwards. The format for slicing in a list is [start:stop:step]. If i wanted to go backwards my step would be -1.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Mesejo and Baily Kocin...this works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the other way around, so from end to beginning. However note that when slicing in python you must specify `aList[start:stop:step]`, `stop` not included. So `[1:3]` will return from the first till the `3d` element (`3d` not included).

So to reverse the order you will have to do `arr[2:0:-1]` as @danielmesejo suggests, given that if you did `arr[3:0:-1]`, in this case the `3rd` element would be included and you would get an error of `index out of range`. Note that you must also specify a `step` of `-1` in to reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for directly expressing the fact that you are indexing backwards is to use

```
arr[-2:,:]
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

Further you can write explicit cast to list, since that is what is given in your question, as

```
(arr[-2:,:]).tolist()
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```